# Yii2 ListView does not iterate over results

Tags: view, iteration, yii2, dataprovider

My code:

Generating data data provider

```
 $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
 $data_provider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
     'allModels'  => $result,
     'key' => 'part_id',
     'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => 15,
     ],
 ]);
```

View:

```
ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $data_provider,
    'layout' => '{items}',
    'options'      => [
        'class' => 'list-view',
        'id'    => 'search_results'
    ],
    'itemView'     => '_result',
]);
```

And _result :

```
 DetailView::widget([
   'model'      => $model,
   'attributes' => [
      'part_id',
   ],
 ])
```

Result:

```
Part Id 1
Part Id 1 
Part Id 1
[...]
```

Why???

If I do var_dump($data_provider) in View I get:

```
 object(yii\data\ArrayDataProvider)[105]
   public 'key' => string 'part_id' (length=7)
   public 'allModels' => 
     array (size=100)
       0 => 
         array (size=7)
           'part_id' => string '1' (length=1)
           [...]
       1 => 
         array (size=7)
           'part_id' => string '2' (length=1)
           [...]
       2 => 
         array (size=7)
           'part_id' => string '3' (length=1)
           [...]
       [...]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've tried the code that you've put here and everything is working fine. Could you please show your database query and a part of your database table content. I don't see anything wrong here.